# Should I use float literals to represent integer numbers as floats in Python?

Tags: python, performance, floating-point, coding-style

Consider a function that is to return a half of a float argument. Should it better be the first or the second?

```
def half_a(x: float) -> float:
    return x / 2

def half_b(x: float) -> float:
    return x / 2.0
```

Is there any performance difference or is there a style convention that would say one of these is better than the other?

Clearly `half_a` looks better and a more complex piece of code may get more readable written this way but in some other languages it is either necessary or preferable to use the `half_b` version to avoid run-time type conversion.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd way is better. But the 1st way is tolerable.

Comment: I second the second

Comment: I'd go with the first now. Python 2 would require the second way to guarantee that floating-point division was used, but between Python 3's `/` operator and the type annotations, I'd prefer the integer denominator to reinforce that you are dividing by *exactly* 2, not some number that is equal to 2 within some floating-point tolerance.

Comment: @PM2Ring I would definitely do the first. Can you elaborate on why the 2nd would be better?

Comment: @chepner I believe you can't divide a float "exactly by 2" this way, the 2 is most probably going to be converted to 2.0 automatically. The question is whether this is going to be done in runtime every single time the function gets invoked or if the interpreter is smart enough to just read `2` as `2.0` in such a case.

Comment: The goal is to provide the most readable function, and for a function named `half_a`, I think that means making it clear the *goal* is to divide by the integer 2 as precisely as possible. As far as the implementation goes, the integer 2 will be passed to the appropriate `__div__` method (`float.__div__`, assuming the call type checks), which will handle any necessary conversions. But no, the integer 2 will not be replaced by 2.0 by the interpreter.

Comment: Integer 2 will convert to 2.0 exactly, but it does have to get converted by `float.__div__` on every call. Sure, that's a pretty cheap conversion, and to be honest, I'm not sure whether it involves creating a Python float object, or it happens at the C level, avoiding the creation of a new Python object. If you really want to micro-optimize performance here, avoid the slow Python function call. And use `x * 0.5` rather than `x / 2.0`; 0.5 is also exactly represented as a float, since it's a small multiple of a small binary power.

Comment: @PM2Ring how is `x * 0.5`better than `x / 2.0`?

Comment: @Ivan Multiplication is slightly simpler than division. For one thing, it doesn't have to handle division by zero. In Ancient Times, it was definitely faster for a CPU to multiply than to divide. I don't know if there's a perceptible difference these days, and if so, if it's relevant to CPython, but old habits die hard. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` divided by `float` is slightly faster than `float` divided by `int`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('n/2', 'n=123456.789') 
0.04134701284306175
>>> timeit.timeit('n/2.0', 'n=123456.789')
0.03455621766488548
>>> timeit.timeit('[n/2 for n in r]', 'r = [n*5/1.1 for n in range(1, 10001)]', number=10000)
5.177127423787169
>>> timeit.timeit('[n/2.0 for n in r]', 'r = [n*5/1.1 for n in range(1, 10001)]', number=10000)
4.067747102254316
```

Comment: Python 3 (as implied by the type annotations) always returns a float, even when both operands are integers.

Comment: Also, the operations are wrapped in function calls, which is an order of magnitude slower than simply performing the division. `float`/`float` alone may be the fastest, but it's not going to be significant in context.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know if there's a performance difference (and if there is, it's definitely negligible). Regarding style, there is also no common convention. However, I would choose the first one, if you are on python 3+. Python 3 has a different operator for integer division. See below

```
x = 2
print(type(x)) # int
print(type(x / 2)) # float
print(type(x // 2)) # int
```

On the other hand, if you are on python 2, you should probably choose the second one, because if your argument happens to be an `int`

```
print(2/5) # 0
```

Comment: `//` is floor division, not integer division. Try `7.75 // 2.5`

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know. I've actually just checked and found out that `/` always returns float even in a case like `4 / 2`.